# RedShift: Join a table with generate series

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table store items level
so if you upgrade your item save in the item upgrade day, eg, 05/10/2019

```
|     day       |  customer |  items  |levels|
| -------       | -------   | ------- | -----|
| 2019-10-02    |    a      |  item1  |  0   |
| 2019-10-05    |    a      |  item1  |  1   |
| 2019-10-09    |    a      |  item1  |  2   |
```

So my goal is to find how many different levels item exist in my table day by day. So in the above table, I cannot tell I have one level-1 item between 05/10/2019 - 09/10/2019

So I needed to count all levels and show in the other days as well. (cumulative sum)

So finally I found something to calculate

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT date date_d,
              d.cust_id,
              item_id,
              item_level,
              last_value(item_level) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY d.cust_id ORDER BY date_d
                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) level_d
       FROM daily d
              LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT cust_id,
                  date date_u,
                  item_id
                  item_level,
                  RANK()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id,date_u,item_id ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC ) rank
           FROM update
            where item_id = '1'
         ) u ON u.cust_id= d.cust_id AND u.date_u = d.date_d AND rank = 1
       GROUP BY
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The result is:

```
|     date       |  customer |  items  |levels|
| -------       | -------   | ------- | -----|
| 2019-10-02    |    a      |  item1  |  0   |
| 2019-10-03    |    a      |  item1  |  0   |
| 2019-10-04    |    a      |  item1  |  0   |
| 2019-10-05    |    a      |  item1  |  1   |
| 2019-10-06    |    a      |  item1  |  1   |
| 2019-10-07    |    a      |  item1  |  1   |
| 2019-10-08    |    a      |  item1  |  1   |
| 2019-10-09    |    a      |  item1  |  2   |
| 2019-10-10    |    a      |  item1  |  2   |
```

but the problem is if the customer is not in the second table we cannot see further so I need a current date for all customers item

What I was thinking to create a generate series like this and join my table

```
SELECT (getdate() - (i * interval '1 day'))::date as date_datetime
FROM generate_series(1,DATEDIFF(day, '2019/10/01', getdate())) i
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

but I got a redshift error!

Any idea how can I join a generate_series data to my table or any different idea

Comment: Often the simplest and best solution is to create a table with every date in it and join to that.

Comment: Amazon Redshift only allows `generate_series()` on the leader node. It cannot be joined with data. Therefore, the best method is to generate a **Calendar table** with dates, that can be joined against. Such a table can also be supplemented with columns like weekday/weekend indicators, start/end-of-month dates, day name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the original table to generate dates:

```
with dates as (
      select '2010-01-01'::date + row_number() over () * interval '1 day' as dte
      from daily d
      limit 5000
     )
. . .
```

You can then use this in your query as you would `generate_series()`.

Note:  This assumes that you have a sufficient number of rows in your daily table.